# how to fetch data from return type void doInBackground to postexecute JSON parsing in android

Tags: android, json, facebook

//Hi to all of you my problem is that my doinbackground is a void type  so i want to fetch data from it to the postexecute, can anyone give me some advice how to transfer data from doinbackground to postexecute?

```
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Session... params) {


            Request r =  new Request(params[0], "me/home");

            Response res = Request.executeAndWait(r);
            try {
            GraphObject go = res.getGraphObject();


        JSONObject json = go.getInnerJSONObject();
        JSONArray jArray;

            jArray = json.getJSONArray("data");

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject currObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
             userId = currObj.getString("id");
            if (currObj.has("message")) {
                userMessage = currObj.getString("message");
            }
            else if(currObj.has("story")){
                userMessage = currObj.getString("story");
            } else{
                userMessage = "no message/story set";
            }
            JSONObject fromObj = currObj
                    .getJSONObject("from");
            String from = fromObj.getString("name");

            HashMap<String, String>newslist = new HashMap<String, String>();
            newslist.put(id, userId);
            newslist.put(message, userMessage);
            newslist.put(name, name);

            list.add(newslist);


            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



            //Log.i("result", go.toString()); //HERE
            return null;
        }
```

//HERE IS MY POSTEXECUTE

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

```
        BaseAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), list, R.layout.list_item, 
                new String[]{id, message , name}, new int[] {R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3, R.id.textView4});
            Log.i("LISTOFUSERID", userId);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        Log.i("message ni tonting", userMessage);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The onPostExecute() task will be automatically called once the doInBackground() task is finished. The doInBackGround() method will return the result of the background process done in the doInBackground().

In your code you could change the return part at the end of the doInBackGround()

```
catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



        //Log.i("result", go.toString()); //HERE
        return result;
```

Then u can access the result in the onPostExecute() task the parameters like this

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){ //Can use any data types
        super.onPostExecute(result);
```